# unable to start debugging on the web server, a problem with the windows iis?

Tags: visual-studio, iis

I think I did something wrong in my IIS. I am getting the error when I am trying to start my project in visual studio. Could you help me?

The error in visual studio:
[image]

The project configuration in visual studio:
[image]

The configuration in ISS:
[image]

I also added to C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc:
127.0.0.1 development.com.local

Comment: Don't use `External Host`, as you are not debugging one.

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: @MrChudz You can refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/error-unable-to-start-debugging-on-the-web-server?view=vs-2019